# Cloudformation IAM role timeout "resource did not stabilize"

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template that experiences timeout during IAM role creation:

`Role XXX is not stabilized`

here is the resource in question:

```
"LambdaExecutionRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
          "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    },
    "Policies": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "WriteLogs",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogGroup",
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": {
              "Fn::Join": ["", [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/lambda/",
                {
                  "Ref": "AWS::StackName"
                },
                "-*"
              ]]}
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "PolicyName": "CreateStack",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
              "cloudformation:CreateStack"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: There are currently "Increased Error Rates and Latencies" shown on the [AWS Service Health Dashboard](http://status.aws.amazon.com/). So, it probably isn't the template itself that is causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein indeed it's working now "Between 8:35 PM and 9:32 PM PDT we experienced increased API error rates in the US-EAST-1 Region. The issue has been resolved and the service is operating normally."